# How to play 'Two-player practice' in Funbridge?

Tags: funbridge

The Funbridge website describes a 2 player practice mode but I can't find it in the app. How do I use it? https://www.funbridge.com/tournaments/training

> This is the only game mode of Funbridge in which you can play with another physical partner at the same time.
>
> You practise with one of your Funbridge friends sitting North and South like at a real bridge table. Your two opponents are always managed by Funbridge artificial intelligence called Argine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by asking your friend to log in. Then you select and click on your friend and scroll down until you see the choise ”practise with your friend”. Click on it and you have started!

Comment: Thanks. This worked in app but seems to be missing on https://play.funbridge.com/